# Grid of images, resize images to fit whole grid of images on screen without having to scroll

Tags: javascript, css, image, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that i would like to show a grid of images on.

I want it to look like this when the grid is 10 in width and 4 in height:
[image]

like this when it is 4 in width and 10 in height:
[image]

First one is working but when it is 4 width and 10 height it looks like this(it scrolls to see the rest)

[image]

this is my code for this component:

```
<template>
  <div style="padding:50px; margin:auto;">
    <v-container>
      <v-row v-for="(rows, rowIndex) in loadedGoal.Dimensions.Height" :key="rowIndex">
        <v-col v-for="(columns, columnIndex) in loadedGoal.Dimensions.Width" :key="columnIndex">
            <v-img
              contain
              v-if="loadedGoal.Id != null"
              src="@/assets/tinyCar.png"
            ></v-img>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import car from '../../assets/tinyCar.png'
export default {
  props: ["goalId"],
  computed: {
    loadedGoal() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedGoal(this.goalId);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This car is just a test image, I do have pictures and a function that gets the pictures from my firebase but I don't think that is relevant for now since it works the same with this picture.

When I load this page it gets the info of the dimensions in an object like this:

```
{
  Description: "test description",
  Dimensions: {
    Height: 3,
    Width: 4
  },
  Goals: [
    {
       imageUrl: xxx,
       xPos: 3,
       yPos: 1
    },
    {…},
    {…},
    {…}
  ],
  Title: "this is the title"
}
```

[Link as requested (codepen)](https://codepen.io/luddeb123/pen/ExxegqK)

Comment: Could you use CSS grid to do this or do you need to use JS for some reason? I think this would do it https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example28/

Comment: @TedWhitehead I would prefer to use JS, and how would that work with scaling? looks like they are always the same predefined size (same problem as i have with VuetifyJS). It is the scaling I am having some trouble with.

Comment: That’s a more complicated problem then if you’re unable to use CSS. It would be helpful if you could post a link to a working demo using https://codesandbox.io or https://repl.it or something similar.

Comment: @TedWhitehead I added a codepen to the bottom of the post